# Monitor execution of script within eclipse using AutoIt

Tags: eclipse, autoit

I am using AutoIt to trigger Eclipse and run Java code (by sending keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>). I would like to check if the Java code terminated.

I want the AutoIt code to run the Java code if the previous Java code has terminated. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: You can check window title, existence of a specified process, text of any control (if possible in window) and many other things. Whats is indicates that the code has terminated?

Answer (score 1):

```
while 1
   $res = ProcessExists("javaw.exe")
   ConsoleWrite(ProcessExists("javaw.exe") & @CRLF)
   if $res = 0 then
      WinActivate("eclipse-workspace","")
      sleep(500)
      send("^{F11}")
   EndIf
   sleep(100)
WEnd
```